# Git commit and push to only working subranch and not main branch

Tags: eclipse, github, push, commit

I created a branch off of main branch (let’s call this branch myBranch). I cloned that repo that is myBranch and brought that remote branch into eclipse; such that now my working tree is myBranch and I’m only wanting to add to myBranch. I created my changes and have brought them into Staged Changes. From eclipse I can now “Commit and Push” or just “Commit”. By selecting Commit and Push, would this only apply the changes into myBranch and not main? I want my changes to only occur in myBranch so later I can create a pull request for the changes in myBranch to merge into main, but only later. I believe I have the logic correct in Commit and Push but I want to know if this will only occur in myBranch and not main? Or should I just commit and push my changes from Git Bash? I need them to appear on GitHub.

I ran git branch -vv and it distributed:

```
*myBranch 0570677 [origin/myBranch] “blah blah” 
main      9b719c5 [origin/main] “blah blah”
```

Comment: Focus on one thing at a time, either "how to use Eclipse here" or "how to use Git here". Your base question is about Eclipse so I snipped the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 0):

> I cloned that repo that is myBranch and brought that remote branch into eclipse

This statement doesn't seem correct to me since your repo should contain all the branches. You can freely switch between them.

Since the currently selected branch is "myBranch" (marked by the asterisk symbol) you will only commit staged changes to this branch. They will be pushed to "myBranch" on the remote.

You might as well do that with Git Bash.